# SpriteKit: SKPhysicsBody slips away

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gravity, skphysicsbody

I have a SKSpriteNode (**Bird**) with a SKPhysicsBody (**Circle**). 
The bird node is affected by gravity and falls down, until it reaches a y position of **100px**.

```
override func didSimulatePhysics() {   

        if (bird.position.y < 100) {

               bird.position = CGPointMake(bird.position.x, 100)
         }
}
```

The problem is, that the physicsBody is moving away from the Node.
The physicsBody should stay centered on the Bird.
As soon as I tap the screen the Bird gets an impulse and moves up. Immediately the physicsBody is back in place.

[image]

This is the physicsBody code:

```
bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.frame.width * 0.5)
bird.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.LeftBoard | PhysicsCategory.RightBoard |  PhysicsCategory.Border
bird.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bird
bird.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
bird.physicsBody!.mass = 1

bird.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
bird.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the velocity. You are forcing the position but the velocity continues after each step.

Also you should typically make such changes in the update method **before** the physics are simulated.

Comment: Great solution and so simpel. Sometimes I feel really stupid. Thanks

Comment: @JonasEster Don't worry, I've encountered this problem numerous times when debugging my game :)

Comment: Now I use a combination of setting the y velocity to 0 and the y position to 100. Otherwise the bird slowly sinks down.